# updating 3 image path in sql at once

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been trying to update 3 columns (product_image1,product_image2,product_image3) from table images. When i add a product i select all three image paths and images path get inserted into table. But when i edit the product and select only 1 or 2 images out of three , so the image which was not selected gets updated as well and null record is inserted into the table for that column. what condition can i use in else to avoid the updation of the image field which i don't select ?

```
       if (($image_extension == "jpg" ||  $image_extension == "png" 
 || $image_extension == "jpeg")){
        UPDATE product_images SET product_image1='$image', 
    product_image2='$image2', 
    product_image3='$image3' 
    where product_id= '$pro_idd'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SELECT query as the following:

```
SELECT product_image1,product_image2,product_image3 FROM product_images WHERE product_id = 1
```

It is impossible to set a default path text for file upload form element for security reasons.  So you have to keep default values in somewhere else.

Set

```
$_SESSION["product_image_1"] = $product_image_1;
$_SESSION["product_image_2"] = $product_image_2;
$_SESSION["product_image_3"] = $product_image_3;
```

After form submission, if the file upload elements are null, then use corresponding session variable's value.

An alternative to session variable, you can add hidden inputs for each image.

Your condition would be like

```
if($_POST["file_upload_product_image_1"]["name"] != ""){
    $product_image_1 = $_POST["file_upload_product_image_1"];
}else{
    $product_image_1 = $_POST["hidden_product_image_1"];    
}
```

Then update three columns to their new values.

Comment: Thank u i got an idea from your suggestion which is much simpler..  i am answering it now..

Answer (score 0):

It updates only the image path which is selected.

```
$ress = "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id ='$pro_idd'";
           $ris =  $obj->fetch_single($ress);
            $img1 = $ris['product_image1'];
            $img2 = $ris['product_image2'];
            $img3 = $ris['product_image3'];
        if($_FILES["image"]["name"] != ""){
        $image = str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES['image']['name']);

    }else{
        $image = $img1;    
    }

    if($_FILES["image2"]["name"] != ""){
        $image2 = str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES['image2']['name']);

    }else{
        $image2 = $img2;    
    }

    if($_FILES["image3"]["name"] != ""){
        $image3 = str_replace(" ", "", $_FILES['image3']['name']);

    }else{
        $image3 = $img3;    
    }
```